# Cannot open include file: 'vector.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++

At the top of the file, I have:

```
#include "vector.h"
```

then I do a:

```
vector<vtarg> targVector;
```

and got the following error

```
Cannot open include file: 'vector.h': No such file or directory
```

Am I missing out something? I tried #include "vector" even more errors.

```
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "vector.h"
// CTargDlg dialog
class CTargDlg : public CDialog {
  // Construction 
public:
    CTargDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
  // standard constructor
    vector<vtarg> targVector;
```

Comment: Modern C++ uses `#include <vector>`.  Either you are using archaic C++ or you are using a non-standard header which is not available on your machine (in the header (include) directories that you requested to be searched, or the system directories).  (And since you are using template notation, you can't be using completely archaic C++, so you should be writing `#include <vector>` and worrying about the `std` namespace.)

Comment: #include "afxwin.h" #include "vector.h" // CTargDlg dialog    class CTargDlg : public CDialog { // Construction public: CTargDlg(CWnd*   pParent = NULL); // standard constructor vector<vtarg> targVector;

Comment: @Sayem: you should look to the original post, no code sample and no good post structure. Only reason why people can answer this easily is because it's a very basic error. Take a similar question in style but about a very difficult topic and people will downvote and close it within minitues, this gets 3 upvotes. Talk about being fair.

Comment: If that's your complete code, then it's no wonder it doesn't compile. You're, at the very least, missing a `};`.

Comment: @KillianDS: No need to get upset :-) . I was just saying that people should leave a comment whenever they downvote a question/answer explaining the reason. Then perhaps those who post incomplete questions/answers will understand. I think in this way these things can be handled more gracefully :-).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use

```
#include <vector>
```

instead, without the `.h` file extension. Furthermore, the `vector` template lives in the `std` namespace, so you should define your vector like

```
std::vector<vtarg> targVector;
```

Also make sure to include whatever headers are necessary for `vtarg`.

Answer (score 5):

You made 3 errors.

First, the include file is called vector, not vector.h.

Second, this vector is an include that's part of the standard C++ run-time library, you need to use the <> include construction, like this:

```
#include <vector>
```

Third, the vector class (actually templated class) belongs to the std namespace.  So you should write:

```
std::vector<vtarg> targVector;
```

Answer (score 4):

The header file is called `vector`, not `vector.h`.

In general, standard C++ headers do not have the `.h` suffix.

If you get "even more errors" wen you `#include <vector>`, then you'll need to solve those errors. But since you haven't said what those errors *are*, it's kind of hard to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `"vector.h"`. The header file for std::vector is `<vector>`. Indeed, all of the C++ standard library headers (save for the C-compatibility ones) do not have a ".h" at the end of them.

Comment: if i do a #include <vector> i end up getting different errors for the vector creation line  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Comment: @craftace: well? What would you like us to do about that? "different errors" is kind of hard to troubleshoot. But I can tell you this much: "you need to fix those errors"

Answer (score 1):

try this alternative

```
include "vector"
```

some compilers, like visual c++ 2010, support this type of notations.
Also if it is a .c file for example xy.c use include"xy".

Answer (score 0):

`#include "vector.h"` is actually the correct way of using this if you are using the stanford library collection.

https://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/cppdoc/Vector-class.html

The problem is that I don't think most compilers are set up to include the stanford library so the file is something you're going to have to include yourself I think.